# jQuery DataTables - TableTools. Activate buttons through trigger jQuery?

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

So I'm using jQuery datatables plugin with tabletools in order to export .csv files. I do not want the buttons to be visible but I still wanted to access these functions through another drop down menu elsewhere on the page.

I have tried hiding the `.DTTT_container` class in CSS and then firing a click event in jQuery:

```
$(".DTTT_button_csv").trigger("click");
```

However it does not save the .csv file.
Is there a way to do this?

Here is my initialising code for `dataTable()`

```
    var table = $("#table").dataTable({
        deferRender: true,
        sDom: "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 queryBreadcrumbs'>r<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'Tf>>" +
            "t" +
            "<'dt-toolbar-footer'i>S",
        oTableTools: {
            aButtons: [
                "csv",
                {
                    sExtends: "pdf",
                    sTitle: "PDF",
                    sPdfMessage: "PDF Export",
                    sPdfSize: "letter"
                }, {
                    sExtends: "print",
                    sMessage: "Generated by ####### <i>(press Esc to close)</i>"
                }
            ],
            sSwfPath: ".../datatables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        language: {
            searchPlaceholder: "Search",
            search: "_INPUT_" //no label
        },
        scrollY: scrollY,
        scrollCollapse: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        order: order
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: It's not possible, because buttons "Copy", "CSV", "Excel" and "PDF" are implemented using Adobe Flash.

See [answer to this post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/18417/table-tools-button-click-invocation-on-custom-link-click) from Allan Jardine, author of jQuery DataTables.

> It's not possible I'm afraid. It's a security feature of Flash, so it can't trigger a file save or copy to clipboard without the user knowing it. It would be a huge problem if you could copy to clipboard on just a hover event!

Alternative solution would be to use [jQuery table2excel](https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel), see [my answer on how to export whole table into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31453159/3549014) for more details. Please note that plug-in may be in early stages of development and has some [Excel format issues](https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/issues/8).

Comment: Thanks @Gyrocode.com - Allan the author of tabletools is going to be releasing a version of the .csv exporter that does not use flash. This is good seeing as flash has many security holes and will probably have discontinued support / compatibility in the future. - so when this comes out within the next few days I'll get my hands on it.

Comment: @ChiMo, glad to hear that Allan is releasing a new version of TableTools, do you have any links confirming that?

Comment: [Export to Excel without Flash](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/27262/export-to-excel-without-flash-and-server-side#latest) . He said in 2 weeks and its been 2 weeks... so I assume it will be released soon.